# How to find an element which starts with something and also ends with something with `document.querySelectorAll`?

Tags: html, dom, css-selectors

There are some elements whose class have a pattern of:

```
view-???-panel
```

Like:

```
<iframe name="view-111-panel"></iframe>
<iframe name="view-112-panel"></iframe>
```

I want to use `document.querySelectorAll` to find them. I know to how to query with "startsWith" and "endsWith":

```
document.querySelectorAll('iframe[name^="view-"]')
document.querySelectorAll('iframe[name$="-panel"]')
```

But I can't find a way to combine them together.

Is it possible to do it all by `querySelectorAll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You CAN combine selectors
`document.querySelectorAll('iframe[name^="view-"][name$="-panel"]')`
https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/ (vanilla JS is the same)